# How to randomly replace text in an itemized list in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, context, random, cloze

I need to randomly replace text with clozes (a.k.a.) write-in-blanks.

I have been using the following code, which works okay in most situations. This randomly replaces words with blank lines, somewhat longer than blank, so if printed, readers can write in the missing word:

```
\definefield[cloze][line]

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\randomtext#1{\def\tmpbuf{}\tmpnum=0\randomtextA#1;;}
\def\randomtextA#1;{\if;#1;\getrandomnumber\randomnumber{1}{\tmpnum}%
      \expandafter\ifcase\expandafter\randomnumber\tmpbuf\fi
   \else \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpbuf\expandafter{\tmpbuf\or#1}%
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \expandafter\randomtextA
   \fi
}

\def\processword{\inframed[frame=off, bottomframe=on, empty=yes]}

\newcount\clozecount
\def\mycloze{%
  \global \advance \clozecount by 1
  \definefield[uniqcloze\the\clozecount][line]%
  \field[uniqcloze\the\clozecount]%
}

\def\processword#1{\randomtext{{\expanded{#1}};{\expanded{\hskip0pt\framed[frame=off, bottomframe=on, empty=yes]{... #1\ ...}\hskip0pt}}}}

\starttext

    \processwords{
    \input knuth
    }
\stoptext
```

This works well, however, I have a new situation where I need to replace text that appears in an itemized list. When I place the itemized list inside the `\processwords` macro, it gets really confused, I suspect possibly replacing `\item`, but I'm not sure:

```
\definefield[cloze][line]

\newcount\tmpnum
\def\randomtext#1{\def\tmpbuf{}\tmpnum=0\randomtextA#1;;}
\def\randomtextA#1;{\if;#1;\getrandomnumber\randomnumber{1}{\tmpnum}%
      \expandafter\ifcase\expandafter\randomnumber\tmpbuf\fi
   \else \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmpbuf\expandafter{\tmpbuf\or#1}%
      \advance\tmpnum by1
      \expandafter\randomtextA
   \fi
}

\def\processword{\inframed[frame=off, bottomframe=on, empty=yes]}

\newcount\clozecount
\def\mycloze{%
  \global \advance \clozecount by 1
  \definefield[uniqcloze\the\clozecount][line]%
  \field[uniqcloze\the\clozecount]%
}

\def\processword#1{\randomtext{{\expanded{#1}};{\expanded{\hskip0pt\framed[frame=off, bottomframe=on, empty=yes]{... #1\ ...}\hskip0pt}}}}

\starttext

    \processwords{
    \startitemize[n]
        \item This is some text.
        \item This is other text.
        \startitemize[1]
            \item This is yet more text.
        \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
    }
\stoptext
```

Note: For this above situation, *every* piece of text clozed will be in items. I tried to find some way to setup  `\setupitemizegroup` to place `\processwords{}` on every text starting with `\item`, but can't find a solution.

This works, however, the file with the lists is `\input`, so its not realistic to manually add `\processwords{}` to everything:

```
\starttext

    \startitemize[n]
        \item \processwords{This is some text.}
        \item \processwords{This is other text.}
        \startitemize[1]
            \item \processwords{This is yet more text.}
        \stopitemize
    \stopitemize
\stoptext
```

How can I get it to replace the text randomly with blanks, without messing up the structure of the itemized lists?

Comment: I'm not a context user, but out of curiosity, I tried `context your-original-file` and got the error `lua error on line 28` (this is the line with the closing brace after`\input knuth`), with the low level message `attr-ini.lua:144: attempt to call a nil value (upvalue 'currentattributes')`.